# Calculating the magnetic moment of a particle in a magnetic field in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, physics

The problem is as follows:
I have a particle in a magnetic field which has components in all the axis and is dependent of all the coordinates

B = (B_x(x,y,z), B_y(x,y,z), B_z(x,y,z))

I solved the equations of motion and found the position (x,y,z) and velocity (v_x,v_y,v_z) of the particle at every step in time.
What I'm trying to calculate is the energy and magnetic moment of the particle to show conservation of each.

Finding the energy is rather simple

E = m / 2 * (v_x.^2 + v_y.^2 + v_z.^2)

and I get the expected result (conservation). However, I'm struggling in calculating the magnetic moment, which is defined as

mu = m * v_perp.^2 ./ (2*B_mag)

where v_perp is the portion of the velocity which is perpendicular to the magnetic field and B_mag is the magnitude of the magnetic field (B_mag = sqrt(B_x.^2+B_y.^2+B_z.^2)). My issue is in carrying out v_perp. I know how to calculate it analytically, but I'm struggling on doing so numerically. I'd be happy to get some help with this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The analytical formulation for the instantaneous velocity and its perpendicular component to the magnetic field should still apply. (Unless if I am misunderstanding something in your question.)

Apply the following equations at each time step.

```
B = [B_x; B_y; B_z]; % magnetic field at particle's position
v = [v_x; v_y; v_z]; % particle's instantaneous velocity

v_prll = (B/norm(B)^2)*dot(v,B); % velocity vector parallel to magnetic field
v_perp = v - v_prll; % velocity vector perpendicular to magnetic field
```

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I'm not quite sure I understand the expression for v_prll. Can you please explain it?

Comment: I can understand why the dot product dot(v,B) is there, but I don't understand the term (v/norm(v)^2) that multiplies it. Should it be multiplied by B/norm(B)^2 since I'm projecting v onto B?

Comment: @FlyGuy, yes! You are correct, and I made the appropriate changes.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know by any chance how I can calculate the two other adiabatic invariants numerically? I'm stuck there as well...

Comment: @FlyGuy. I certainly do. If you google Chen's Plasma Physics textbook, you'll find a section of the three adiabatic invariants for a particle in a magnetic field. I can help you with that, but let's go ahead and close this answer since it answered your original question.

Comment: Yes, I am working with Chen's book and I am familiar with them. I'm just having a difficulty writing it down numerically. Anyway, I'll start a new thread and hopefully we can discuss that there. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Here's a link to the question in case you miss out on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214540/calculating-the-second-and-third-adiabatic-invariants-for-a-particle-in-a-magnet

Comment: I apologize if I'm nagging you, but I'm still stuck on this and I'd be happy to get some help with it. :)